# Access a returned variable from another function

Tags: javascript, function, object, sharepoint, scope

I have a function that is mapping some data from API calls. The data is limited to display only 10 elements. Because of the limitation, the REST API returns also a key called `data.d.__next` containing URL with the next data to be displayed.

I would like to take this `data.d.__next` to use somewhere else so I used `return {variable}` in the function.

The problem with this solution is that the browser's console is complaining about data not iterable.

How can I use this variable called `remainingDataToDisplay` outside of `function mergeR(){}` to get the string it contains?

The code is similar to the one below:

```
function mergeR(data) {
  const [data1, data2] = [...data];
  const results1 = data1.d.results;
  const results2 = data2.d.results;
 
  const mergeRData = /// some code
  
  const remainingDataToDisplay = data1.d.__next; //typeof it: string

  const htmlCode = mergeRData.map(){} 

  return {remainingDataToDisplay}

}

function validation() {
  // call the remainingDataToDisplay variable here
  var {remainingDataToDisplay} = mergeR();
  // if I'm trying to access this variable, I'm getting error data is not iterable
}
```

Comment: The error message indicates that you're trying to iterate over the variable, not just access it. Show how you're trying to use the `remainingDataToDisplay` variable.

Comment: You're missing the argument to `mergeR()`. So `data` will be `undefined`, and `[...data]` will get an error saying it's not iterable.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the suggestion. I used var {remainingDataToDisplay} = mergeR(data); and browser's console is throwing error: data is not defined. If I don't add parameter data, then I'm getting back data is not iterable although I don't try to iterate anything. Otherwise, the data is working as expected and displaying properly. The link returned by REST API is looking like: "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TheList')/Items/?+"$select=Title...."

Comment: The argument should be the response from the API, shouldn't it?